# Scale 2D Texture to model scaling to prevent streching

Tags: c++, opengl

I have an OpenGL 3.3 program whichts has different objects in, for example a simple cube. The cube's dimensions are 1x1x1 (vertices from -0.5, -0.5, -0.5 to 0.5, 0.5, 0.5) and is textured with one 2D texture on each side. The texture is repeatable (seamless).

With my actual code the model scaling looks like this (ignore the actual texture):

[image]

After scaling like this:

[image]

In this case the texture in should stay at size in z-direction but repeate over the z-axis.

Is there a good way to scale the texture properly to the model's scaling to prevent it from stretching? Or do I have to create a 3D texture?

The problem i found is that in my shader I get only the (scaled) point of the cube, for example -0.5, -1,5, -0.5 but the texture's coordinates are only 2D (0.0, 0.0) and I don't know which side of the texture I have to scale since I don't know which side it will currently be rendered on.

For for the sake of completeness, however, the vertex shader code:

```
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 aNormal;
layout (location = 2) in vec2 aTexCoord;

out vec2 TexCoord;
out vec3 FragPos;
out vec3 Normal;

uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;

void main()
{
    FragPos = vec3(model * vec4(aPos, 1.0));
    Normal = mat3(transpose(inverse(model))) * aNormal;
    TexCoord = aTexCoord;
    gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(aPos, 1.0);


    //gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(aPos, 1.0f);
    //TexCoord = aTexCoord;
}
```

The fragment shader looks like this:

```
out vec4 FragColor;

in vec2 TexCoord;

// texture samplers
uniform sampler2D texture_diffuse1;
uniform vec4      color;

void main()
{
    FragColor = color + texture(texture_diffuse1, TexCoord);
}
```

Comment: what you want it to look like? and what if the scale is not integer?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, stretching is the actual scaling, there's no way around it. Maybe you could have the wooden frame unscaled and only scale the inner squares. That would need you to increase polygon count and only stretch the inner square, this way the frame would only be made longer and not thicker.

Comment: In this case the texture in should stay at size in z-direction but repeate over the z-axis.

Comment: It might not work but what if, you pass your scale matrix to the vertexshader, it should be identity at the beguining and then you do something like: `vec4 texCoord4 = scaleMatrix * vec4(TexCoord, 0, 1); `TexCoord = vec2(texCoord4)` you might also need a `glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);` it will not work if you scale on z but with a bit of fixing you can accomplish what you want maybe

Comment: @DraykoonD I had this option already in mind but how you say it dosen't work with the z-axis.

Comment: you are applying your scale matrix on a 2D vector, the z value of your scale transformation will not be taken in account. that's why the third component of texCoord4 is 0.